# How to set a Multiline-TextView non-editable

Tags: android, textview, android-inputtype

I have a TextView which is from inputType="textMultiLine". The problem is, when I click (and hold) in a free part of the TextView (a part where is no text), it presents me the option of pasting text in. And when I do so, it overwrites the existing text with the text in the clipboard. 
I don't want this behavior. What can I do to make the TextView non-editable?

this is the xml-Code:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1. Hello, Dies ist ein Beispielsatz. \n2. Dies ist der zweite Satz."
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        />
```

**Note:**
If I remove the inputType="textMultiLine", the option of pasting text is no longer presented. But I want the TextView to be multiline.

Comment: did you try with `android:focusable="false"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this make you **`TextView`** to **`android:longClickable="false"`**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1. Hello, Dies ist ein Beispielsatz. \n2. Dies ist der zweite Satz."
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.setFocusable(false);
```

> Setting this to false will also ensure that this view is not focusable
>   in touch mode.

**XML**

```
android:focusable="false"
```